# Java Applet HttpPost to apache via HttpClient/HttpPost and InputStreamBody

Tags: java, applet, apache2, apache-httpclient-4.x

Program is an applet designed to take some files, process them, send them through a ZipOutputStream, and upload the (usually rather large) zip file to the server. It is using Apache HttpClient 4.2.1 (and ancillary libraries). My post request is executing in a privileged space. The issue I'm having is Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) refuses to take the request. I get an error in the Apache error logs, "chunked Transfer-Encoding forbidden".

If I use wireshark to capture the connection, the request looks like:

```
POST /data/FileUpload.php?userId=21 HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=PjgV56PRG1T0eeWZNfM3Gumc8v0p8j
Host: 192.168.2.16:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)
10be

--PjgV56PRG1T0eeWZNfM3Gumc8v0p8j
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ZipFile"; filename="JavaUploaderZipStream.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

The code that executes this request is:

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    ZipCompressionInputStream zipStream = new ZipCompressionInputStream(fileList);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
    InputStreamBody uploadPart = new InputStreamBody(zipStream, "application/zip", "JavaUploaderZipStream.zip");
    reqEntity.addPart("ZipFile", uploadPart);
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    try {
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);
    } finally {
        httpPost.releaseConnection();
    }
```

From what I can tell, Apache 2.2 is supposed to accept chunked data. I don't see any switches that reject it. It seems to be accepting the HTTP/1.1 connection. I'm at a loss as to why it just flat refuses anything I try.

Comment: You would have to provide some Apache configuration data, and you are probably asking in the wrong place. Try serverfault.com.